# How to properly use alias memory in Qemu

Tags: qemu

I am trying to create a memory alias in qemu but it does not work.

My cortex-m3 binary is linked to these addresses:

```
FLASH:        0x70010000, size 0x70000
VECTOR TABLE: 0x10000000, size 0x800 
RAM:          0x10000800, size 0x20000
```

And as cortex-m3 expects the vector table to be present at address 0, I thought it would suffice to create an alias region at address 0 that refers to the table at address 0x10000000:

```
MemoryRegion* systemMemory = get_system_memory();
MemoryRegion *flash = g_new(MemoryRegion, 1);
MemoryRegion *ram = g_new(MemoryRegion, 1);
MemoryRegion *ram_vectors = g_new(MemoryRegion, 1);
MemoryRegion *vector_alias = g_new(MemoryRegion, 1);

memory_region_init_ram(flash, NULL, "flash", 0x70000, &error_fatal);
memory_region_add_subregion(systemMemory, 0x70010000, flash);

memory_region_init_ram(ram_vectors, NULL, "ram.vectors", 0x800, &error_fatal);
memory_region_add_subregion(systemMemory, 0x10000000, ram_vectors);

memory_region_init_alias(vector_alias, NULL, "flash.vectors", ram_vectors, 0, 0x800);
memory_region_add_subregion(systemMemory, 0, vector_alias);

memory_region_init_ram(ram, NULL, "ram", 0x20000, &error_fatal);
memory_region_add_subregion(systemMemory, 0x10000800, ram);
```

But Qemu stops with error message:

```
qemu-system-arm: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x98700306
```

I don't see what is wrong with memory setup in Qemu.

**EDIT:**
If I link the vector table to address 0 (and also change the memory region setup in qemu) the trace from qemu looks like this:

```
arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm -M mymachine -cpu cortex-m3 -kernel kernel.elf -
monitor none -chardev udp,id=char0,port=4444,localport=4445 -chardev 
udp,id=char1,port=4446,localport=4447 -serial chardev:char0 -serial chardev:char1  -semihosting -nographic -d exec

Trace 0x7f1976abe0c0 [0: 000008a0] _start
Stopped execution of TB chain before 0x7f1976abe0c0 [000008a0] _start
Trace 0x7f1976abe0c0 [0: 000008a0] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe0c0 [000008a0] index 1 -> 0x7f1976abe340 [000008ae]
Trace 0x7f1976abe340 [0: 000008ae] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe340 [000008ae] index 0 -> 0x7f1976abe4c0 [000008aa]
Trace 0x7f1976abe4c0 [0: 000008aa] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe4c0 [000008aa] index 1 -> 0x7f1976abe340 [000008ae]
Trace 0x7f1976abe340 [0: 000008ae] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe4c0 [000008aa] index 0 -> 0x7f1976abe600 [000008b4]
Trace 0x7f1976abe600 [0: 000008b4] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe600 [000008b4] index 1 -> 0x7f1976abe800 [000008be]
Trace 0x7f1976abe800 [0: 000008be] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe800 [000008be] index 0 -> 0x7f1976abe980 [000008ba]
Trace 0x7f1976abe980 [0: 000008ba] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe980 [000008ba] index 1 -> 0x7f1976abe800 [000008be]
Trace 0x7f1976abe800 [0: 000008be] _start
Linking TBs 0x7f1976abe980 [000008ba] index 0 -> 0x7f1976abeac0 [000008c4]
Trace 0x7f1976abeac0 [0: 000008c4] _start
Trace 0x7f1976abebc0 [0: 00003d60] main
```

The reset jump address is fetched correctly and execution starts at 8a0 (_start)

But if I link the vector table to start of RAM at 0x10000000, and aliases that to 0x0, qemu does not fetch the correct jump address:

```
Trace 0x7ff0ad83b0c0 [0: 00000000] <<<<-----THIS SHOULD BE 700100a0
Stopped execution of TB chain before 0x7ff0ad83b0c0 [00000000] 
Trace 0x7ff0ad83b0c0 [0: 00000000] 
Trace 0x7ff0ad83b1c0 [0: 7003a5d0] MemFaultHandler
Stopped execution of TB chain before 0x7ff0ad83b1c0 [7003a5d0] MemFaultHandler
Trace 0x7ff0ad83b1c0 [0: 7003a5d0] MemFaultHandler
Linking TBs 0x7ff0ad83b1c0 [7003a5d0] index 0 -> 0x7ff0ad83b5c0 [7003a5f0]
Trace 0x7ff0ad83b5c0 [0: 7003a5f0] MemFaultHandler
```

The interesting part here is that it jumps to MemFaultHandler, and that jump address is fetched correctly from the vector table, but not the start address!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give us your QEMU command line -- lots of weird behaviour of guests in QEMU can be traced back to "command line is incorrect".

0x800 is an implausibly small amount of RAM -- less than 1K. You don't say what hardware you are trying to model, but I doubt it has 0x800 bytes of RAM -- it probably has a larger region that you should be modelling. I mention this because QEMU has problems with executing from blocks of RAM less than 1K in size, so you might be running into that. Instead of having two RAM regions that are right next to each other at 0x10000000 and 0x100000800, you should just have a single RAM region of whatever size the RAM is, starting at 0x10000000.

I would also recommend using QEMU's -d debug logging to trace where the program is trying to execute from. This can catch a lot of weird "didn't do what I expected at startup and crashed" bugs. This should tell you why execution ended up at 0x98700306.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes the RAM is larger, the first 0x800 bytes are reserved for the vector table, so I created a separate region for that part.  I will try with one ram region only as you suggested.

Comment: I have tried with using only one large ram region located at 0x1000_0000 and created an alias region located at 0x0 and referring to the first 0x800 bytes of that region. It did not work. Same crash as before. See more details in the EDIT of the original post.

Comment: I have a feeling you're running into a QEMU bug here where if the initial loaded ELF file puts the vector table in RAM but the CPU reads it via an alias it doesn't read the correct values. If so, then you can work around it by putting the alias the other way around -- so the ram region is at 0 and the alias at  0x10000000. (The problem only exists for the initial PC/SP read on CPU reset, because at that point we haven't actually written the ELF file into RAM); once execution starts the ELF file contents are properly in RAM and accessible via either the region itself or the alias.)

Comment: I tried it. Put ram at 0 and alias at 0x10000000, but the result was exactly the same as before.

Comment: I hardcoded the initial_msp and initial_pc in target/arm/cpu.c to the expected values and then it executes without crashing. So the aliasing works as expected, its just the initial loading of SP/PC that is done wrong.

Comment: So my big question now is: how do other people do this? I mean most chips does not have any memory mapped to address 0x0 I think.

Comment: I think mostly people write their ELF files to have a physical load address that matches where the vector table really is, ie load to address zero, rather than loading to a high address and then relying on the aliasing. Also, not all boards have this sort of alias. The 'stellaris' series boards have flash memory (which we model as read-only-memory) at address zero. The various MPS boards have real RAM at zero.

Also if you have an ELF file then QEMU will honour the ELF entry point, so a binary written to work at the ELF entry point and without needing the initial SP setup will also run OK.

Comment: The line rom = rom_ptr(0); in target/arm/cpu.c causes qemu to search for address 0 among the load addresses found in the loaded elf file. If it also had searched for the address aliased by 0, (0x10000000), it would have found the correct rom block. But I don't know if the memory regions are available at this point.

Comment: Yes, that's the underlying cause of the bug -- we look at the rom file, not in memory, so we don't know what the memory aliasing is like.